# reading indices and values of a matrix from a file and assigning the value

Tags: r, matrix

Say I have a file with 3 columns. The first 2 columns are the indices(row,column) of a matrix. the third is the value I need to store in the matrix. The first 5 lines of the file looks like this.

```
     V1 V2   V3
[1,] 13 14 4950
[2,] 20 50 4949
[3,] 22 98 4948
[4,] 30 58 4947
[5,] 43 48 4946
```

Say I read this file with the following command:

```
idx<-as.matrix(read.table("data.txt"))
```

I create a matrix b and store it in there with this code but it doesn't seem to work. I found a work around by using a for loop which seems to work fine but takes a long time.

```
b<-matrix(0,100,100)
b[idx[,1],idx[,2]]<-idx[,3]
```

when I try the following I get:

```
> b[13,14]
[1] 126
> b[22,98]
[1] 115
```

which doesn't match the third column. Sorry if this is an elementary question. What is going on here?

Comment: Are you sure `idx[1,3]==4950`? It sounds like when you do `read.table` you might have some non-numeric values in your third column which converts the column to a factor.  That would also assume that you are not showing us the exact data/code you are running because it still seems unlikely to get 126 that way.

Comment: I checked my file _ its all just numbers. There is no text. Does read.table read it as factor even if there are only numbers?

Comment: I would look at `dd<-read.table("data.txt"); str(dd)` just to see what all the data.types are. `read.table` will not turn all numerical data into a factor. Do you have missing values? Also when you read the data into `dd` i'm guessing the columns are called `V1, V2, V3`. You can find non-numeric values with `dd$V3[is.null(as.numeric(as.character(dd$V3)))]`.

Comment: When I did that I got V1 - int, V2- int and V3- num. Is that the problem? I def donot have missing values. 

when I try to find non numeric values - I cant find anything. So weird.

Comment: Those are all numeric fields. I don't understand where 126 comes from then. Does the value 126 appear at all in data.txt? Is is possible you have (13, 14) listed twice in data.txt?

Comment: Did a search for it, there is no 126. Every number in the third column is converted to some random number after reading it. 

I should also say that scanning it and using the the code that Richard Scriven presented didnt actually work, still keep getting the same numbers. I think for now, i am going to just stick with writing for loop and individually assigning the values, which seems to work.

Comment: Something's not checking out. When you do `readLines("data.txt", n=10)` do you see the values you expect? Are you sure you are reading in the correct file? If this method doesn't work, there's no reason to think a loop would be any different.

Comment: Yes, pretty sure I am reading in the right file. In fact, I do the for loop on the same variable idx that I read in from the file. I could send you the file if you want to tinker around. I am really curious why this is happening.

Comment: Perhaps you could post your code and data to a pastebin site. It's hard because I do not get that behavior with the sample data above.

Comment: I figured out what was going wrong. it was how I was reading the file. I needed to set stringsasfactors to false.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider `scan` for reading matrices.  With the result, it outputs a message with the number of lines read.  Then you can construct your new matrix.

```
> s <- scan("data.txt")
# Read 15 items
> m <- matrix(s, 15/3, 3, byrow = TRUE)
> b <- matrix(0, 100, 100)
> b[ m[, 1], m[, 2] ] <- m[, 3]
> b[13, 14]
# [1] 4950
> b[22, 98]
# [1] 4948
```

Comment: Or `matrix(s, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)`. user1775614, I'm guessing MrFlick is right, and the advantage of `scan` is that it assumes everything is the same type (double by default). You could also specify `colClasses` in `read.table`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, figured out what was going on - I needed to set "stringsASFactors = F" while reading the file and everything worked like a charm. I am not sure why that worked...but it did.